# How to sort the second column of csv file using LINQ query in Power shell

Tags: powershell, linq

E.g , My list( $dataList) has following values
Note: Header may differ each files. I would like to pass column's position instead column name.

```
$dataList = new-object System.Collections.Generic.List[string]
CSV file example below

Code,name,gender 
1,BB,M
2,CC,M
3,DD,F



  $sortedValues = [Linq.Enumerable]::OrderBy($dataList, [Func[string,string]] { $args[0]})
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to use `Enumerable.OrderBy()` instead of just `Sort-Object`?

Comment: Yes, when am using sort-object, performance is tool slow.

Comment: And you only want to operate on the second column, all other data can be discarded?

Comment: not like that , i want to have entire data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to parse the data using `Import-Csv`/`ConvertFrom-Csv` and then grabbing the column name from the first record:

```
$data = Import-Csv .\path\to.csv
$list = [System.Collections.Generic.List[psobject]]::new([psobject[]]$data)

$columnName = @($data[0].psobject.Properties)[1].Name

$sorted = [System.Linq.Enumerable]::OrderBy($list, [Func[psobject,string]]{ $args[0].$columnName })
```

---

If your files are large and you want to avoid the overhead of parsing the input data with the `*-CSV` commands, all you need to do is skip the header line:

```
$list = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()
$header = Get-Content .\path\to.csv |Select -First 1
Get-Content .\path\to.csv |Select -Skip 1 |ForEach-Object {
    $list.Add($_)
}

# Remember to write header manually back to result file
$header |Set-Content .\path\to\result.csv

[System.Linq.Enumerable]::OrderBy($list, [Func[string,string]]{ $args[0].Split(',')[1] }) |Add-Content .\path\to\result.csv
```

Comment: Second code i.e. split is works fine, Thanks. did not tried first command.